# How Do I custom drag and drop style of NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa

I have some questions about drag and drop of view-based NSTableview.

[image][image]

1. How to change drag and drop highlight color?
2. How to change drag and drop rectangle shape(width and height)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a view-based NSTableView?

Comment: Yes, I'm using view-based NSTableView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this in your `NSTableRowView` subclass:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self)
        return nil;
    // etc...

    [self setDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle:NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleNone];

    return self;
}

- (void)drawDraggingDestinationFeedbackInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSRect drawRect = [self bounds];
    // Tweaking the size of the drawing rectangle...
    aRowRect.size.height--;
    aRowRect.size.width-=2;
    aRowRect.origin.x++;

    NSBezierPath *backgroundPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:drawRect];
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [backgroundPath fill];
    [[NSColor greenColor] set];
    [backgroundPath stroke];
}
```

Of course, if you aren't building a Christmas-themed app, you'll want to change those colors.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for helping.
But I still have a question, If I drag item to border(up and down) The NSTableRowView still draw blue line. How do I change stroke color? thanks.

Comment: @CocoaUser I've done that once in a cell-based `NSTableView` by overriding the private method `_dropHighlightColor` in my `NSTableView` subclass (return value should be an `NSColor` object). Try that, it should work... (I don't believe that there's another way, but I could be wrong)

Comment: Hi Simon,
You are kind and resolve all of my questions. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SimonM I know this question is old, but I don't see a `dropHighlightColor` method on my `NSTableView`. I'm trying to customize the color of the blue line between rows. Any chance you have done this with Swift recently? Thanks!